# Combining 2 select statement and join sql

Tags: c#, sql, .net, asp.net-web-api

I'm currently having a problem on sql statement

here's my code

```
SELECT [Cities].ProvinceId,[Cities].Name,[Provinces].Name
FROM [Cities] JOIN Provinces
ON [Cities].ProvinceId = [Provinces].id
UNION
SELECT [Regions].RegionName,[Countries].CountryName
FROM [Regions] JOIN Countries
ON [Regions].RegionId = [Countries].RegionId
```

so basically what I am trying to do is that get the cities,province,region and countries.

I have 4 regions by the way which is 
ASEAN = 1,ASIA = 2,WORLDWIDE = 3,DOMESTIC = 4

so DOMESTIC needs to be on the cities and province only because they are places local here in my country

and regions 1,2,3 are for countries but I could join theme because of these error

> All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists.

by the way I Applied it like this on my API

```
var provinces = await _provinceRepository.GetAll();
var cities = await _cityRepository.GetAllCities();

var result = provinces.Join(cities, p => p.Id, c => c.ProvinceId, (p, c) => 
    new DestinationModel
    {
        Region = null,
        City = c.Name,
        State = p.Name,
        Continent = null,
        Country = null
    }).ToList();

return Ok(result);
```

Now you can see my problem is that for now I can only get provinces and cities
the region and country are still null. Could someone help me with my query.

Comment: Add `null` to the shorter select list, so they'll have the same number of select list items.

Comment: A way to get around this error is to include dummy columns so that the number of columns does match,

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: .. also does SQL Server allow different datatypes to be unioned ... As i assume ProvinceId to be a int type..

Comment: @jarlh add `null` where exactly sir . I'm sorry

Comment: @RaymondNijland those id are all int sir

Comment: then it will not work -> https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b4c7a3cb0160c5d7deaebda18d563737 .. i assume you are using SQL Server (MSSQL) and not MySQL.. Because the `[]` is invalid syntax in MySQL..

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample as tabular text and the expected  result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> so basically what I am trying to do is that get the cities,province,region and countries.

Does this do what you want?

```
SELECT c.Name as city, p.Name as province, co.name as country,
       r.name as region
FROM Cities c
JOIN Provinces p ON c.ProvinceId = p.id
JOIN Countries co ON p.CountryId = co.id
JOIN Regiones r ON co.RegionId = r.id;
```

To me, it seems like a more sensible result.